# Defining functions Scheme-style in Common Lisp, without defun

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

In Scheme, you define functions like

```
(define f (lambda (x) ...))
```

In particular, you can do something like this

```
(define f (g))
```

where g is some function returning a function. Is it possible to do the same in Common Lisp, i.e. to associate a function symbol with a given anonymous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found the answer in Paul Graham's book *ANSI Common Lisp* (after looking the second time; p. 99):

```
(setf (symbol-function 'f) (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

achieves (for most intents and purposes) the same as

```
(defun f (x) (* x x))
```

Comment: `defun` does much more than that. `(macroexpand '(defun f (x) (* x x)))`

Comment: That's why I qualified the statement with "for most intents and purposes". This is mentioned in Graham's Book as well.

Comment: "For most intents and purposes" is quite subjective. If you're compiling files, `defun` informs the compiler about the function to avoid reference warnings in the same file, even if the function is declared after the references. Most implementations annotate where they found definitions such as `defun`s, so that an IDE or Emacs+Slime can jump to them. You don't get any of that with `setf` of `symbol-function`.